# Replace String with Previous String based on Conditions IN R

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I am trying to replace a particular string with the lagging string in R but somehow not getting the desired result.

what I have tried till now:

```
data3 <- data2 %>%
filter(ID== 1) %>%
mutate(String=  case_when(String== 'JKLMNOP' ~ lag(String)))
```

Data:

```
ID DATE      String    
1  9/19      ABCDEF
1  9/18      ABCDEF
1  9/17      ABCDEF
1  9/16      JKLMNOP
1  9/15      JKLMNOP
1  9/14      JKLMNOP
```

Desired Output:

```
ID DATE      String    
1  9/19      ABCDEF
1  9/18      ABCDEF
1  9/17      ABCDEF
1  9/16      ABCDEF
1  9/15      ABCDEF
1  9/14      ABCDEF
```

LAstly, I want to group this for every ID so that there is no overlap.

Comment: your example is not clear enough to me. What happens when there are 3 different strings for the same ID? i.e. `length(unique(data2$String)) > 2`. How is it the expected output in that case? Also.. is it correct that the time is inverted?

Comment: do you just want to replace every instance of String with the first String for each ID?

Comment: I want to replace every instance of a particular string with the previous known string

Comment: That's not what your expected output says! Based on what you're saying the expected result should be: `String = c(NA, "ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", "ABCDEF", "JKLMNOP", "JKLMNOP")`. Can you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep information of only unique `ID` and `String` value and then use `lag` for the `String` that we want to change. Join this new data with the original dataframe to get the lagged string value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  distinct(ID, String) %>%
  mutate(new_string = ifelse(String == 'JKLMNOP', lag(String), String)) %>%
  left_join(df, by = c('ID', 'String'))

#  ID  String new_string DATE
#1  1  ABCDEF     ABCDEF 9/19
#2  1  ABCDEF     ABCDEF 9/18
#3  1  ABCDEF     ABCDEF 9/17
#4  1 JKLMNOP     ABCDEF 9/16
#5  1 JKLMNOP     ABCDEF 9/15
#6  1 JKLMNOP     ABCDEF 9/14
```

Comment: Conceptually, this works fine. Now trying to optimize it for a huge dataframe